# How exactly does the Awaiting Support Reply field work in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a workflow which pulls from a saved search.

---

**The saved search has the criteria:**

Awaiting Support Reply - is true

Stage - is any of Open, Escalated

---

**The result I am getting are not as expected:**

I post a ticket from my work account (it goes into the list).

A member of the service desk team (handle cases) responds and it disappears from the list.

I reply from my work account and it does not reappear in the list.

---

I have also tried this from an external email address in case its picking up my internal address as a member of staff or something weird?

Can anyone please advice? Does the person replying have to be a customer in the system for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on the case status. Configure what you want it's value to be for each case status you have configured.

Setup -> Support -> Case Statuses

Comment: Lovely thank you very much, ill check this in the morning

Comment: Can confirm this is exactly how it works. Thank you so much Brian

Comment: So off the back of this, if the case itself isnt updated at all, the field seems to auto update based on if the customer or the agent has last replied

Comment: @JoshWhiddett No. Receipt of replies/mail can trigger workflows/scripts which often change the case status. The Awaiting Support will have the value of whatever is configured for the case status a case is set to by the script/workflow.